# Hoe to fetch Google FCM notification analytics using analytics label in Node?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending FCM notifications with analytics label and I need to fetch analytics of one of these messages like this

```
const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = express();
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert('./xxxx-firebase-adminsdk-gexvw-d24bfcb6ba.json'),
  databaseURL: 'https://xxxx.firebaseio.com'
});
const analytics = admin.analytics();
const analyticsLabel = 'abc';
const getAnalyticsReport = async (analyticsLabel) => {
  const report = await analytics.getAnalyticsReport({
    metric: 'engagement_rate',
    dimension: 'app_version',
    filter: `analytics_label == '${analyticsLabel}'`,
    timeRange: '2023-11-12'
  });
  const engagementRate = report[0].metrics[0].value;
  return engagementRate;
};
const displayAnalyticsReport = async () => {
  const engagementRate = await getAnalyticsReport(analyticsLabel);
  console.log(`The engagement rate for the analytics label '${analyticsLabel}' is ${engagementRate}`);
};
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
  displayAnalyticsReport();
});
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
 "@google-analytics/data": "^4.0.1",
 "express": "^4.18.2",
 "firebase-admin": "^11.11.0",
 "firebase-analytics": "^1.0.1"
}
```

But I get this error

```
const analytics = admin.analytics();
TypeError: admin.analytics is not a function
```

How to fix this to be able to fetch analytics label report?